# How to horizontally position div overlapping the right border of a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have vertically aligned a circle within a rectangle div. Now, I need that circle to be positioned on the right-border of the parent div while also maintaining responsiveness. In other words, if that parent div resizes its width, the circle should remain glued to the right-border.

Here is an example of how I want the circle positioned:
[image]

Here is a JSFiddle of what I have so far. https://jsfiddle.net/jqvf8t2L/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <span>My Text</span>
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40%;
}

.circle {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

span {
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

I have tried putting `align-self: flex-end` on the `circle` element and absolutely positioning the `circle` element to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```css
.outer {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
}

.circle-holder {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  right: -10px; /** half your outer padding **/
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.circle {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span>My Text</span>
  <div class="circle-holder">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. Can you explain to me the necessity of `circle-holder`?

Comment: if you are to position the circle as absolute and move it using `left/right/top/bottom`, even though it works, it will fail when the parent div is of variable height. So, a far better approach is to have a container div that can take the height of the `.outer` div so that `.circle` inside the can be centre aligned.